# Sent mail going to spam folder?

Tags: php, email, spam

I searched this topic but there wasn't anything useful for me.

**CODE:**

```
public function sendActivation($name, $user, $pass, $activationKey)
{
    $to = $user;
    $subject = 'Account Activation';
    $headers = "From: noreply@domain.tld\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message = "<div id='mail' style='height: auto; width: 500px;background-color: #DDDDDD; font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;'>
    <p>Hello dear $name and thanks for your choise!</p>
    <p>Your details:</p>
    <p>Username: $user</p>
    <p>Password: $pass</p>
    <p><br /></p>
    <p>Here there is an activation link. Please click on it to activate your account.
    If you don't activate your account in next 24 hours, your account will be deleted automaticly.</p>
    <p><a href='" . BASE_PATH. "/register/activation/$user/$activationKey'>Activate Your Account!</a></p>
    </div>";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail going to spam rarely has much to do with the code, unless you're sending spammy content.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

1. Make sure the computer sending the email has a Reverse PTR record
2. Configure DomainKeys Identified Mail in your DNS and code
3. Set up a SenderID record in your DNS

You should also see if your server is on any blacklists, using something like [this blacklist checker](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx/). If you're on one, nothing you're doing is going to help until you get the listing cleared up.

Comment: Oh my god:x.  This is really what I want. thanks in advance :x