# PHP Form processing not sending email

Tags: php, forms, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sent mail will going to spam folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601645/sent-mail-will-going-to-spam-folder)

I have a simple html form:

```
<div id="content">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<form name="contact" action="form-to-email4.php" method="post">
<label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="contact_name" /><br />
<label>Email Address: </label><input type="email" name="contact_email" /><br /><br />
<label>Message: </label><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50">
</textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form><br /><br />

</div>
```

and a PHP script to process and email the information

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST')
{
//This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
die;
}
$name = $_POST['contact_name']; $email = $_POST['contact_email']; $message = $_POST['message'];

if ($_POST['contact_name'] == "" || $_POST['contact_email'] == "" || $_POST['message'] == "" )     {
    echo "Please fill in all boxes.";}
else {

$email_from = 'chris569x@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Message from the SGU Website"; 
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the SGU website.\n". 
"Message From: $name \n".
"Email Address: $email \n".
"Message: $message \n";  
$to = "chris569x@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thanks4.htm');
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=thanks4.htm'>";}
?>
```

The script seems to process correctly.  I get the message if i try to access the PHP directly, I get the message if not all required fields are filled in, and I get re-directed to the page at the end of the script, but I never receive any emails.  What am I missing?  (I am very new to this)

Comment: are you running this script on a windows machine?

Comment: Check your spam folder.  If you have access to the mail server logs (which seems unlikely) look in there too

Comment: run some check on mail function, does it return TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Spam folder... it is always the simple things!  At least I wasn't going crazy and my scripts do work.

Comment: did you check if the email was sent? did you check if the email was rejected? did you check if the email was junked as spam?